# Sharepoint 2010 and VS 2010, new way to build site columns?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I noticed that VS2010 has some great new ways to build Sharepoint content. List definitions and Content Types amongst other things. What I didn't spot was an easy way to build in Site Columns.

In Sharepoint 2007, I used to do this by hand. I've gotten quite used to it, but I am sure there must be a less time consuming way to do things in MOSS 2010 / VS 2010.

Previously I

- Created the feature
- Defined the site columns (fields)
- Created the content type
- Created the list definition and default instance
- Localized and such

I can see how MOSS 2010 gives you a head start with content types, but am I correct in saying there still is no GUI for the whole creation process, and fields still need to be done by hand?

Or what am I missing out on :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the custom columns needs to be created by hand. Although there are wizards to generate feature and content type schema.

Comment: So basically what you're saying is if you know how to do stuff for Sharepoint 2007 by hand, you should continue to use this tried and trusted method, even if its more complex? I've run into a few problems pretty hard to solve because the moss 2010 abstraction hides a lot of the details.

Comment: No, I am not saying that. We should use wizards to generate basic skeleton of features and then do hand crafting for custom requirements.

Comment: I wouldn't call the new sharepoint 2010 way of doing things completely ultimate, but after weighing up the pros and cons, it has its benefits over the 2007/wsp builder route.